# How to build OpenSSL for Android on Windows with MSYS

Tags: android, openssl, cross-compiling, msys, building

As the title suggests I've been trying to build OpenSSL library for Android. Basically, I am following [this guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html).

I have installed msys-base via MinGW installation manager. [image: MinGW installation manager.]

ActiveState perl is installed at "C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe".

Having run "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat", I set environment variables:

`CC=C:\android\android-ndk-r11c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe`

`AR=C:\android\android-ndk-r11c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ar.exe`

`ANDROID_DEV=C:\android\android-ndk-r11c\platforms\android-23\arch-arm\usr`

The following line from the guide is causing issues:
`./Configure shared android or android-armv7` , so I used just `./Configure shared android` as it doesn't seem to know android-armv7. Not sure if it's correct though.

After configuring I run `make build_libs` which results in the error related to windows-style paths:
[image: OpenSSL path confusion]

Fixing perl path manually is not a big deal, but having checked the generated Makefile, I noticed that it contains windows paths everywhere. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I believe its an unsupported configuration. It looks like the guide you are following is for Linux, not Windows. Your best bet is probably install [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), set up a Ubuntu 16 VM, and then work from Linux. For completeness, `./Configure LIST | egrep '(android|mingw)'` provides you with some of the targets of interest. None of the targets cross Android and MinGW.

Comment: Well, the guide states "If your development platform is Windows, you need msys with perl v5.14 or later to build OpenSSL." So I assume it's for windows. As far as I understand, mingw is needed only in order to provide the unix-like environment.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Two other suspects are (1) MinGW was abandoned a long time ago, so it may not be the best platform for you now; and (2) the instructions likely apply to OpenSSL 1.0.1 or 1.0.2. I still think you should consider a Ubuntu VM to avoid MinGW pain points. Downgrading to OpenSSL 1.0.2 may help.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. The reason why I strived to avoid Ubuntu approach is the need to install all this android stuff there. But maybe you are right and that is still easier than making it work in MinGW.

Comment: If you give Ubuntu a try, then checkout [Andoid](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki. It will give you an idea of what needs to be done when using OpenSSL's build system. I'm not familiar with Qt, so I'm not sure how different the procedures are.